# C-Shell : variable in variable

Tags: linux, variable, csh

I want the value of variabe `${var}_err_num`, but i can't do it.

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set list = "book bus apple"
foeach var $list
   set err_num
   *
   *
   @err_num = $err_num + 1
   set ${var}_err_num = $err_num
end

echo ""
echo "# Summary"
foeach var $list
   echo "$var error num : ${${var}_err_num}" ; # Error occured
end
```

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27606472), you need to use `eval`. Perhaps:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
set list = "book bus apple"
set err_num = 0
foreach var ($list)
   @ err_num += 1 
   set ${var}_err_num = $err_num
end

echo ""
echo "# Summary"
foreach var ($list)
   eval echo \$var error num : \$${var}_err_num ; # Error occured
end
```

(I fixed some syntax errors in your script, like the typo in `foreach` and so on.)

The output:

```
$ csh -f foo.csh

# Summary
book error num : 1
bus error num : 2
apple error num : 3
```

Comment: If my post helped you, consider accepting it. https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers